# How to create container using Azure data factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to execute a stored procedure inside a pipeline and export it to Azure storage.

I can achieve it but the Azure storage container was created and set manually in the dataset.

Now I want to create first the Azure storage container inside the pipeline before starting the export.

What activity should I used in pipeline?

Comment: Can you share your complete setup or a snip of the configured pipeline. Source, sink ? more details to suggest accurately

Comment: I just wanted to know how to create a container using azure data factory pipeline. What activity should I use?

Comment: Maybe use an Azure Function? See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65190284/create-blob-storage-container-via-azure-data-factory

Comment: Yah I achieved it already using Azure Function. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it using functions, also please take a look at my answer if helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 1):

### **Method 1:**

Parameterize sink dataset with container path to dynamically create container.

If a SQL source getting data using procedure.

[image]

Storage sink dataset having parameter

[image]

Assigning the parameter created, in place of filesystem/container field.

[image]

Providing a value for the container to be created dynamically. You can optionally provide a value of your choice, maybe from an output value of another activity in pipeline. Here I am using the system variable **PipelineRunID** whcih would have a unique value for each run and would be able to identify or track specific result in storage.

Or create a **pipeline parameter**, and use that in place to provide value to dataset parameter.

[image]

After a successful run, you can see the container created in storage.

[image]

[image]

### **Method 2:**

You can use a WebActivity to call the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-container) to create a container in blob storage.

Here is a sample configuration:

[image]

**1.** Configure URL, set your storage account and the container name to be

> `https://<your-storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>?restype=container`

**2.** Should be a PUT method

**3.** Set the version of operation. For more information, see [Versioning for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services)

> `x-ms-version: 2020-10-02`

**4.** Date: UTC time of the request, can dynamically set using Date functions.

**5.** Authorization: Specify how you want to authorize this request, see [Authorize requests to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage).for different options. I have used Shared key.

**6.** Your preferred authentication mode.

After successful request, you would receive no response data apart from the status code 201 and headers.